# ILDASM code for overloaded methods when polymorphism is used

Tags: c#, polymorphism, overriding

When i execute the following code the following is shown in the ILDASM. My doubt is that even though the child class method will be executed why is ILDASM showing that the Baseclass method is called. Is it because the instance is of type BaseClass? If it's the reason how is the base class accessing a child class method?

```
 class BaseClass
    {
        public virtual void Mover(long a,long b)
        {
           Console.WriteLine(a*b+"LongBaseClass");
        }
    }
class ChildClass : BaseClass
{
    public override void Mover(long a, long b)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(a+b+"LongChildClass");
    }
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
       long a=10,b=20;
       BaseClass bcc=new ChildClass();
       bcc.Mover(a,b);
}
```

```
callvirt instance void practiceonly.BaseClass::Mover(int64, int64)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [E]ven though the child class method will be executed why is ILDASM showing that the Baseclass method is called?

Because ILDASM shows what the code looks like **at compile-time**, and method overriding is resolved **at run-time**<sup>†</sup>. Regardless of whether you are calling

```
BaseClass baseClass = new ChildClass();
baseClass.Mover(42, 42); // Yields 1764LongBaseClass
```

or

```
ChildClass childClass = new ChildClass();
childClass.Mover(42, 42); // Yields 1764LongChildClass
```

both will translate to

```
callvirt instance void BaseClass::Mover(int64, int64)
```

This is because the compiler does not know whether an overridden method exists and whether you intend to call it.

What method is actually called is determined at runtime based on the object being referred to by the reference (in the latter code sample, the reference is of type `ChildClass` while in the first it is of type `BaseClass`).

---

<sup>†</sup>In .NET there is a difference between **static** or **compile-time polymorphism** and **dynamic** or **run-time polymorphism**. Method overriding is dynamic polymorphism. An example for static polymorphism would be method overloading.

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 1):

The `callvirt` IL code is used for virtual methods to ensure that the correct override is called.  There's a fairly good explanation of the difference between `call` and `callvirt` [here](https://www.dotnetforall.com/call-and-callvirt-instructions-in-net-il/), or some more technical discussion [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.callvirt).

Each class has a method table (known as the Virtual Method Table or VTable) which contains pointers to the exact code to execute for each method defined in the class and its parents.  Rather than containing an entry for every overloaded version of a method through the hierarchy it contains a single method pointer for each method signature.  When a class overrides a virtual method that class gets a different method pointer in the method's slot.

`callvirt` and `call` take a method metadata token as a parameter and use the properties of that token to determine the desired method and how to locate it.  `callvirt` will use the VTable to locate the method to use based on the supplied method metadata, always getting the most-derived version that is valid for the type of the object that the method is being invoked on.  `call` on the other hand will invoke the method that you specify, which is useful when you need to do `base.Mover(a, b)` without getting stuck in an infinite loop.

So to find the current best overload we only need the metadata for the original `virtual` or `abstract` definition, since all overrides will occupy the same slot in the VTable for their respective classes.  The only time it will use anything other than the base is when you are using `call` to invoke a specific override.

---

Just to make things nicely confusing for everyone however, it seems that `C#` will use `callvirt` to invoke pretty much any non-static method on a reference type, except for `base.method()` type calls.  All normal method calls (including property get/set) on class instances use `callvirt`.  It's been that way since the early prototype days of C# [in 1999](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericgu/2008/07/02/why-does-c-always-use-callvirt/) apparently, and is almost certainly (there's some fuzzy language) due to `callvirt` doing an additional check on the `this` pointer to ensure that it isn't `null`.

Comment: During the early betas of .NET, regular methods used `call`. but code like this succeeded: `MyClass m = null; m.SomeMethod();`. Users complained and a switch was made to use `callvirt`, so that code like that would throw as expected.

Comment: @Flydog57 Yep.  Essentially it just adds a null `this` check that `call` doesn't do. Wonder if non-nullable reference types will change this?

Comment: @Corey my question still remains unanswered. My question wasn't about callvirt. My question is that why is ILDASM showing that the base class method is getting called when in reality the child method is called.

Comment: @NVIswaNihar I'll expand on the second paragraph, which is kind of an answer to your question.